# git submodules out of sync & submodule init/refresh doesn't resolve it

Tags: git, synchronization, git-submodules

Suspected original cause: I had two laptops sync'ing to iCloud and both had the git repository (with submodules) in question. After some git add/commit/push that acted rather strange (due to the sync), I stopped the sync. Then I found one of the two  submodules no longer acting as a submodule. That is, when I look at the repo on GitHub the subdirectory for that submodule no longer had the "arrow" in the folder icon.

Trying to get it working again. Tried `git submodule init` , `refresh`, etc., and git complains that I've added a submodule.

I'm guessing I will have to find the commit where I lost the submodule and cherry pick (?) to get it back since the repository has had many changes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't ever put Git repositories in a folder synced by a cloud syncing service, such as iCloud.  What you're seeing is repository corruption, which is very common when using a cloud syncing service for a repository.

Comment: I realize that now ... didn't realize the sync was turned on.